# PHP and MySQL time-based quiz application

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a time based quiz project with PHP and MySQL and storing results as in below table.

**Table: score**

```
sid |Question_ID|answer |is_correct|User_ID|score|score_calculated|time_taken
1   |10         |Manager|Y         |  1    |200  |  0             |3.2
2   |10         |Emp    |N         |  2    |200  |  0             |2.4
3   |10         |Manager|Y         |  3    |200  |  0             |6.5
4   |10         |Other  |N         |  4    |200  |  0             |8.3
5   |11         |Yellow |N         |  1    |300  |  0             |2.3
5   |11         |green  |N         |  2    |300  |  0             |5.8
6   |11         |Red    |Y         |  3    |300  |  0             |6.4
7   |11         |Red    |Y         |  4    |300  |  0             |9.1
```

Score column contain the mark for each question

Score calculations based on:

- Correct answer used minimum time = 100%
- Correct answer used 2nd minimum time = 75%
- Correct answer used 3rd minimum time = 50%
- Other correct answers = 25%
- Other incorrect answers = 0

The above calculated values need to be updated on ** 'score_calculated' ** field.
Can anyone please suggest a query or method to solve the scoring process?

Comment: do the calculations in php before you insert the results? you can write a long ugly `if()/case` structure in sql, but it'll be ugly to maintain.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai @ whizzzkid : Thank you for your reply. These calculation can be done only after four entries are arrived, because we need to get the 1st shortest time, 2nd shortest time and so on.  Could you please light me with an example of view or trigger. Thanks again.

Comment: @whizzzkid please see above comment..

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for your reply. This is not possible for current situation, because the four entries form different users should be arrived before calculating(to get time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by `Ranking` records by `time_taken`. I will edit this later with the query...

Answer (score 1):

The best way fot your problem are MysqlTrigger.
On every answer submission (after the insert), you can call the trigger.

Comment: @ mikecurl91 These calculation can be done only after four entries are arrived, because we need to get the 1st shortest time, 2nd shortest time and so on. Could you please give me an example